# How to add Identity 2.0 users to an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

So I am trying to grasp `EF6` and it's use of `Identity 2.0` for making a many to many relationship. It is Visual Studio 2013 and the MVC 5 template.

I have a fresh MVC app with the following models:

```cs
public class Meeting
{
    public Guid MeetingID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Attendees { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; } 
}
```

Then I scaffold a controller and views for `Meetings`. Now, for instance, if I just wanted to add every `user` as an `attendee` to my `meeting`, I would imagine that I could modify the `Create` action to look like the following:

```cs
public ActionResult Create(Meeting meeting)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        meeting.MeetingID = Guid.NewGuid();
        db.Users.ForEachAsync(u => meeting.Attendees.Add(u));
        db.Meetings.Add(meeting);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else...
}
```

However I don't think it's working because I don't see it in my `LocalDB` and if I add this to the detail view for a meeting I get no results:

```cs
@{foreach (var item in Model.Attendees)
{
    <li>@item.UserName</li>
}}
```

As a final note, I have two users in the LocalDB, test and test2.

What tutorial or documentation will allow me to make this work?

*** Edit ***

So I have tried your suggestion (I'll admit, I am unfamiliar with async and await and how to implement it), and I had to modify the controller to allow me to use await so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly now, but I got the following to compile and I get run time error of 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' :

```cs
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Meeting meeting)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            meeting.MeetingID = Guid.NewGuid();
            await db.Users.ForEachAsync(u => meeting.Attendees.Add(u));
            db.Meetings.Add(meeting);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

(is it possible I'm missing some setup of my model on Entity Framework? The project is exactly the code shown above plus defaults.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself :)

(Drumroll)

You forgot to add `await` before your `ForEachAsync` line:

```
await db.Users.ForEachAsync(u => meeting.Attendees.Add(u));
```

Without `await` the application happily continues on and saves the record, all before that async process has completed.

**UPDATE**

Most likely you haven't initialized the `Attendees` collection. Just set it to a new `List<ApplicationUser>` in your constructor.